# Video.js Player not working with Jquery Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello for some reason when I scroll down with the Jquery Infinite Scroll the Video.js player on the next page turns into a normal html 5 player. http://orgasmal.com/ (SFW)
The weird part is the player works fine when it's on its own. http://orgasmal.com/test/ (SFW) Here is the code for the player if it helps:

```
 <video id="ex2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
 controls preload="auto"; loop  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
 <source src="http://codmemes.com/video/test.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 </video>
 <script>_V_("ex2", {}, function(){
  var myPlayer = this;
  myPlayer.size(640,600);
  myPlayer.play();

   });</script>


 function custom_infinite_scroll_js() {
if( ! is_singular() ) { ?>
<script>
var infinite_scroll = {
    loading: {
        img: "http://codmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/27-1.gif",
        msgText: "<?php _e( 'Loading More People...', 'custom' ); ?>",
        finishedMsg: "<?php _e( 'Shit, you just hit the bottom of the internet.', 'custom' ); ?>"
    },
    "nextSelector":".nav-previous a",
    "navSelector":".navigation",
    "itemSelector":".box",
    "contentSelector":".icontent"
};
jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll );
</script>
<?php
}
}
 add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_infinite_scroll_js',100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to re-initialise video.js when the new video is inserted via the infinite scroll plugin, (I cant see the exact code as it is minified)

Try placing the video.js code (shown above) in a named function and calling that when the new scrolled content is inserted

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, I tried wrapping the players in <div class"box"></div>, but still no dice ..... I'll post the infinite scrolling code up above maybe it will help.